# Suppose you have an array of N elements. You need to find for how many i, Ai + A(i+1) is a square number. Is this question trivial? If so how?

Tags: c++, c

I just wanted to know if the above question is trivial or not. More importantly, how can you recognize if an algorithm is trivial?

Comment: If you need to know if an element + the next element is a square number, this can be done in *O(N-1)*

Comment: “Trivial” is not a formally defined term in general mathematics or computer science. As commonly used, I would say it means a problem or feature essentially vanishes. I would not say a problem of testing some property is trivial unless there is a solution of complexity O(1) (meaning we essentially know the answer just from the problem statement, without needing to look at its specific data) or at least has complexity much simpler than first thought (e.g., there is an O(n) solution when the previous best known solution was O(n^3)). This problem is not trivial in that sense.

Comment: This question needs details and some clarity. As of now, it seems that "No." would be an answer. For "Yes, because ..." it would need a definition of "trivial". Both confuses me to the point that I consider the question not answerable, at least not in the way StackOverflow is meant to be used.

Comment: I understand sorry for the trouble; Nonetheless, I got the answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what do you mean by trivial. If you talk about complexity, it is O(n*M(N)) where M(N) is the complexity of the underlying multiplication algorithm with N maximum of the array's values and n is the length of the array. 
If you talk about implementation, it is one loop with one check that the sum of the neighbors is a perfect square. If the elements fit into int, double etc. you have sqrt function in the standard library. If your elements are arbitrary length integers or float point numbers, you either need to use an appropriate library or implement the handling of these numbers on your own, which might be not trivial.
This understanding should help you to answer your last question